# I changed the hostname on Ubuntu 20.04 and now I am locked out

Tags: hostname

I changed hostname and it locked me out from VNC, putty or RDP.(timeout)
Yet the server is running and can be accessed with IP address. Hostname cannot be resolved and cannot go back to change it without access.

Answer (score 1):

You say you can access it with IP address? then you should also still be able to SSH/putty into it. Just don't use the hostname and use the IP to connect until you resolve the problem..
Ergo, if the old hostname was server01 bound to ip 192.168.1.17 and you changed hostname to server02 and then you timed out, and you can still ping 192.168.1.17, then you should still be able to connect to that.